# python equivalent for php mcrypt tripledes

Tags: python, encryption

I have the following PHP functions to encrypt and decrypt data. They are not written by myself. Now the encrypted data is stored in a database and I have to read it from there and display it to the user using python. I tried to google it but I didn't find anything that fit my needs.

Hope somebody has a hint for me where to start or a useful link.

```
function Decrypt($input) {
      $key = "xxx"; // 18 Signs
      $iv  = "xxx"; // 8 Signs
      return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, $key, base64_decode($input), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
}

function Encrypt($input) {
   $key = "xxx"; // 18 Signs
   $iv  = "xxx"; // 8 Signs
   return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, $key, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Python interface to the standard mcrypt library](http://labix.org/python-mcrypt). Its documentation is...not so much...but I poked around in it and came up with some code that I *think* duplicates the PHP you posted:

```
import mcrypt
import base64

KEY = 'xxx'
IV = 'xxx'
ALGORITHM = 'tripledes'
MODE = 'ecb'

def encrypt(data):
    cryptor = mcrypt.MCRYPT(ALGORITHM, MODE)
    cryptor.init(KEY, IV)
    return base64.b64encode(cryptor.encrypt(data))

def decrypt(data):
    cryptor = mcrypt.MCRYPT(ALGORITHM, MODE)
    cryptor.init(KEY, IV)
    return cryptor.decrypt(base64.b64decode(data))
```

Comment: I only had to edit: cryptor.init(KEY.ljust(KEY_SIZE, '\0'), IV) because my key was to short. I set KEYSIZE = 24